# Create a new column based on an existing column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a question in SQL. I have an existing data table like following:

[image]

And would like to make the selection into a list. The rule is as following: if an ID selects a product, we will provide it a value 1. Otherwise, the value is 0. For example, ID 1 choose product A and B. So the corresponding is_tap for product A and B is 1, and for C is 0, since there is no selection. The selection here is limited and known. The final table will be something like:

[image]

How can I generate this table in SQL? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What’s the rules for it? Can you do it as a computed column?

Comment: Good question. Let me update this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have *derived tables* (the subqueries) producing all possible combinations of id and selection.

`LEFT JOIN` the original table. Use a `case` expression to return 1 if row exists, otherwise 0.

```
select t2.id, t3.selection, case when t1.id is not null then 1 else 0 end
from (select distinct id from t1) t2
cross join (select distinct selection from t1) t3
left join t1 on t2.id = t1.id and t3.selection = t1.selection
order by t2.id, t3.selection
```

Demo at https://dbfiddle.uk/-sS-bvxM